# How to handle session management on cloud hosting in asp.net webform based website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, cloud-hosting

Let us say i have a website developed in asp.net webforms on .net 4.0 frame work and this needs to be migrated to cloud hosting like `rackhosting`.

This website currently uses asp.net default membership for user management and also uses several session variables for storing temporary variables.

This website is hosted on a dedicated server hosted inhouse.

so my question is

- How to make it work on cloud hosting
- One way of doing could be using MS Sql Server based session management
- What else i need to take into consideration to make it work on cloud hosting

I have no experience with cloud hosting as one gets confused with the cloud hosting architecture provided by service providers. Microsoft Azure, Amazon etc..

any pointer to a good article and code examples would be great to start with

Comment: Will you be using more than one server? i.e will you need session state across different servers?

Comment: Yes, i need session across the servers... let us say i store image value in session after it is uploaded and if at that moment save request is handled by another server then session will be null.

Comment: I remember i had this issue with Server Farm,  on shared hosting my session kept coming null when i was trying to save the session value stored in session variable. problem in that case was resolved by adding machine key so that each user session will always be handle by that particulate server. But i am not sure how it works on cloud..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Session State Provider that will span the servers.
e.g. one that uses [App Fabric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361709%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) (or other caching provider) or [Sql Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For sharing sessions you have 2 options: 
1. Sticky sessions, easiest to implement because there are no changes to do in code, but you will not be able to autoscale (add or reduce the number of machines based on load). This will be just a setting on your load balancer, so you need to check if the load balancer of your cloud provider has this. 
 
2. Out of proc session and here I suggest to use the ASP.NET Redis session provider (supported by Microsoft). Both AWS and Azure provide Redis as a servce, so it is easy to start with, you don't need to think of its administration. Most important out of proc will mean some code changes, at least marking your classes that go in session as Serilizable, but you will be able to autoscale.